# How to show an alert using javascript when the option from select box choose secondly

Tags: javascript, alert

I have grid which has 'N' number of rows. I have a select box on each row with three options.

```
<tr>
 <td>
   <select id="1">
    <option>YES</option>
    <option>NO</option>
    <option>IGNORE</option>
   </select>
 <td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>
   <select id="2">
    <option>YES</option>
    <option>NO</option>
    <option>IGNORE</option>
   </select>
 <td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>
   <select id="3">
    <option>YES</option>
    <option>NO</option>
    <option>IGNORE</option>
   </select>
 <td>
</tr>
```

I would like to show an alert when the user selects IGNORE secondly. I dont want to show the alert when the user select 'IGNORE' on first time.

Let us consider select ID#1, i dont want to show an alert if the user choose 'IGNORE' or 'YES' for the first time. But if the user has already clicked on 'YES' or 'NO' and then tries to click on 'IGNORE' next time then i want to show an alert.

This function has to work on all select box. Can somebody help to resolve this.

Comment: So, you want to fire an alert if and only select#2 is changed to IGNORE? What do you mean "on row basis"? you already got three rows there. BTW, using numbers as IDs isn't a good idea. Referencing them from stylesheets and selectors will need some extra work.

Comment: so what you need is a counter that tells you how many ignore have been pressed and then if statement that runs when counter==2?

Comment: @amenadiel: Let us consider ID#1, i dont want to show an alert if the user choose 'IGNORE' or 'YES' for the first time. But if the user has already clicked on 'YES' or 'NO' and then tries to click on 'IGNORE' next time then i want to show an alert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a javascript map that maintains count of how many time a value in dropdown is selected. If that count is more than 1 for a dropdown, you can show alert.

```
<tr>
 <td>
 <select id="1" onchange="updateSelectionCount('1')">
  <option>YES</option>
  <option>NO</option>
 <option>IGNORE</option>
</select>
<td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> 
<select id="2" onchange="updateSelectionCount('2')">
<option>YES</option>
<option>NO</option>
<option>IGNORE</option>
</select>
 <td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
 <select id="3" onchange="updateSelectionCount('3')">
<option>YES</option>
<option>NO</option>
<option>IGNORE</option>
 </select>
<td>
</tr>
<script>
var map = new Object();
function updateSelectionCount(comboId){
    var e = document.getElementById(comboId);
    var selectedValue = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    if(selectedValue=='IGNORE'){
        if(map[comboId]==1){
            alert('selected second time');
        }else{
            map[comboId]=1;
        }
    }else{
        map[comboId]=1;
     }

}
</script>
```

Comment: Hi @GreenComputers i have updated my comment with code. Please check it.

Comment: Thanks for your great time Hemal. It works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use jquery you can also do this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready(function() {
       $('select').on('change', function() {

            if (typeof this.count == 'undefined')
            {
                this.count = 0;
            }
            else{
                if (this.count>=0 && this.value=="2")
                {
                    alert("my Warning")
                }
                this.count += 1
            }
        })
    });
  </script>
   <select>
    <option value="0">YES</option>
    <option value="1">NO</option>
    <option value="2">IGNORE</option>
   </select>

   <select>
    <option value="0">YES</option>
    <option value="1">NO</option>
    <option value="2">IGNORE</option>
   </select>
```